# Running Jasmine testing on Ubuntu. Page not found

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ubuntu, rubygems, jasmine

I installed Jasmine-gem on my project without rails usage as my app is php based on Ubuntu. I go to localhost:8888 as said and get page not found in any browsers. Am I missing a basic HTML page like the standalone install or something?.

I know this isn't a full gems issue because compass and other gems function fine.

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong, it is able to find the specs in the command line.

I could just load jasmine standalone but if is possible to get this running, I would really appreciate it!

Thank You.

Comment: You are supposed to start jasmine server first by executing `rake jasmine`, after that a test page should be available at localhost:8888. Here is a [Usage](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem#usage) section in the docs.

Comment: That I know. I should mention that I am in a Windows/vagrant/virtualbox with Ubuntu. Thanks for your response.

Comment: So you run jasmine server on virtual machine, but unable to access it from your own machine?

Comment: I guess it is a problem with a port forwarding and not with your code/jasmine. Do you have Vagrant set up correctly to forward virtual machine's localhost:8888 to your local address? ([Vagrant docs on port forwarding](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html))

Comment: Was just looking at that. Something I will have to test later. Thank you for your help and quick responses. I will give an answer if I solve anything here.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention I am running Windows. Since Jasmine will run on its own server, I installed it directly on Windows and it works fine. Thanks again for your help. Sometimes you wonder which way you want to go on a shared file system.